# How to bind a not visible value to Hyperlink URL in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, parameter-passing

I have a Hyperlink on one column in my gridview. Lets say this column has different fruits..

Fruits

Apple
Banana
Kiwi
Orange

My fruits should be Hyperlink and when i hover or click on the link i want to send the id's from the fruit to next page and not the Fruitnames.

How can i do that? I only manage to make links to next page where the names from fruits Comes as Parameter and i dont want that. I also dont want to make a select on the id's from the fruit because then it Comes as a new column in my gridview and it's not interesting to see the id's of the fruits but it important to send them as Parameters because i Need them on next page.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="FruitName" 
        DataTextField="FruitName" HeaderText="Fruits" 
        DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Cashier.aspx?FruitID={0}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the DataNavigateUrl Fields to "FruitID" (Or whatever your ID column is called) that should insert the ID of the fruit in the URL, while keeping the text of the URL as the Fruit Name.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="FruitID" 
        DataTextField="FruitName" HeaderText="Fruits" 
        DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Cashier.aspx?FruitID={0}" />
```

Edit:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ...
      AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
              <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="FruitID" 
                   DataTextField="FruitName" HeaderText="Fruits" 
                   DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Cashier.aspx?FruitID={0}" />

              <!-- Any other Columns you need to be visible -->
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Yes but in my SQL i don't make any SELECT on the FruitID and then i get an error  that says that it can't find the FruitID in the SQLDataSource.

Comment: Also if i add FruitID in my select then i get one more column in my Gridview and i dont want that so that's why im not doing it ..

Comment: If you want the FruitID in the URL, you will have to select it in the SQL statement.  To not have the column be generated, set the AutoGenerateColumns="false" in the GridView, you will then have to manually write out the columns you want in the <Columns> tag